# Hybridauth Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id Solution

Tags: yii, hybridauth

I have resolved this issue : 
for some reason, the response from /oauth/access_token became a valid JSON. The parse_str function was parsing a wrong format. For me changing this lines in the libraries/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/Facebook/base_facebook.php resolved the issue:

Please change this code

```
public function setExtendedAccessToken() {
    $response_params = array();
    parse_str($access_token_response, $response_params);

    if (!isset($response_params['access_token'])) {
      return false;
    }   
}

public function getAccessTokenFromCode($code, $redirect_uri = null) {
    $response_params = array();
    parse_str($access_token_response, $response_params);

    if (!isset($response_params['access_token'])) {
        return false;
    } 
}
```

**Change to :**

```
public function setExtendedAccessToken() {  
    $response_params = json_decode($access_token_response, true);

    // Not a valid JSON format
    if(!isset($response_params['access_token'])) {
        // Try to parse
        $response_params = array();
        parse_str($access_token_response, $response_params);

        if (!isset($response_params['access_token'])) {
            return false;
        }
    }  
}

public function getAccessTokenFromCode($code, $redirect_uri = null) { 
    $response_params = json_decode($access_token_response, true);

    // Not a valid JSON format
    if(!isset($response_params['access_token'])) {
        // Try to parse
        $response_params = array();
        parse_str($access_token_response, $response_params);

        if (!isset($response_params['access_token'])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it [tag:yii] or [tag:yii2]?

Comment: This code for  Yii 1

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for this question :**
for some reason, the response from /oauth/access_token became a valid JSON. The parse_str function was parsing a wrong format. For me changing this lines in the libraries/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/Facebook/base_facebook.php resolved the issue:
**change code**

/**
   * Extend an access token, while removing the short-lived token that might
   * have been generated via client-side flow. Thanks to http_bit_ly_b0Pt0H
   * for the workaround.
   */
  public function setExtendedAccessToken() {
    ...

```
$response_params = array();
parse_str($access_token_response, $response_params);

if (!isset($response_params['access_token'])) {
  return false;
}

...
```

}

...

/**
   * Retrieves an access token for the given authorization code
   * (previously generated from www.facebook.com on behalf of
   * a specific user).  The authorization code is sent to graph_facebook_com
   * and a legitimate access token is generated provided the access token
   * and the user for which it was generated all match, and the user is
   * either logged in to Facebook or has granted an offline access permission.
   *
   * @param string $code An authorization code.
   * @param string $redirect_uri Optional redirect URI. Default null
   *
   * @return mixed An access token exchanged for the authorization code, or
   *               false if an access token could not be generated.
   */
  public function getAccessTokenFromCode($code, $redirect_uri = null) {
    ...

```
$response_params = array();
parse_str($access_token_response, $response_params);

if (!isset($response_params['access_token'])) {
  return false;
}

...
```

}

**To:**

/**
   * Extend an access token, while removing the short-lived token that might
   * have been generated via client-side flow. Thanks to http_bit.ly_b0Pt0H
   * for the workaround.
   */
  public function setExtendedAccessToken() {
    ...

```
$response_params = json_decode($access_token_response, true);

// Not a valid JSON format
if(!isset($response_params['access_token']))
{
  // Try to parse
  $response_params = array();
  parse_str($access_token_response, $response_params);

  if (!isset($response_params['access_token'])) {
    return false;
  }
}

...
```

}

...

/**
   * Retrieves an access token for the given authorization code
   * (previously generated from www_facebook_com on behalf of
   * a specific user).  The authorization code is sent to graph_facebook_com
   * and a legitimate access token is generated provided the access token
   * and the user for which it was generated all match, and the user is
   * either logged in to Facebook or has granted an offline access permission.
   *
   * @param string $code An authorization code.
   * @param string $redirect_uri Optional redirect URI. Default null
   *
   * @return mixed An access token exchanged for the authorization code, or
   *               false if an access token could not be generated.
   */
  public function getAccessTokenFromCode($code, $redirect_uri = null) {
    ...

```
$response_params = json_decode($access_token_response, true);

// Not a valid JSON format
if(!isset($response_params['access_token']))
{
  // Try to parse
  $response_params = array();
  parse_str($access_token_response, $response_params);

  if (!isset($response_params['access_token'])) {
    return false;
  }
}

...
```

}